# Range Hood has plug, no outlet on the wall

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens

I removed my upper cabinets and bought a range hood. There is a BX coming from the hole above my stove. There is no wall outlet. Is there any way I can convert this to make the new range hood work? I don't want to reinstall cabinets but also don't want to dip into my budget for serious electrical work. The house is old an has enough problems. Thank you!

Update- I used an old box that I got from the hardware store and used it to install a new outlet. Everything is working great and looking lovely! Thank you!

Comment: what is available in terms of electrical connections?

Comment: Is this not as simple as wiring up an electrical box with an outlet to that BX conduit you have available?

Comment: You need to help us with more info on the BX cable. Please post some clear pictures. BX cable should terminate in a box and should at least be capped with wire nuts. Does it have power to it?

Comment: PLease post the name & model number of the hood you bought so we can peek at the installation manual.

Answer (score 2):

It's common enough for range hoods to be supplied with a cord and plug.  It's also common for range hood connections to be made via BX.

The range hood should be designed so the cord-and-plug connection can be removed, presumably exposing a standard 1/2" trade size knockout (more like 3/4"), and then the BX can be fit up to that with a BX fitting. There'll be a compartment that opens up to hook up the wires.

Comment: And of course if this one isn't, then just wire the BX feed to an outlet box.